# Required permissions for integration between Azure Pipelines and Github

Tags: github, azure-pipelines

What privileges do [Azure Pipelines Bot](https://github.com/azure-pipelines-bot) require from a GitHub user asking for a pipeline re-run? Currently, it reacts to `/azp run` comment of the user with the following error message:

```
Commenter does not have sufficient privileges for PR 9999 in repo org/repo
```

The whole integration works flawlessly for other users of the same repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, This problem seems to be that the user does not have sufficient repository permissions.

Please refer to the following steps to check:

1. Responses to this commands will appear in the pull request discussion only if your pipeline uses the [Azure Pipelines GitHub App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#github-app-authentication). Make sure your pipeline uses the Azure Pipelines GitHub App.
2. Repository **collaborators** can comment on a pull request to manually run a pipeline. Please check whether the user is collaborator. If not, please invite collaborators to a repository.
3. Make sure that your membership is public in the repository's organization, or directly add the user as a repository collaborator. Azure Pipelines cannot see private organization members unless they are direct collaborators or belong to a team that is a direct collaborator.

How to invite collaborators to a repository:

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name,  click **Settings**.
3. In the left sidebar, click **Manage access**, then click **Invite a collaborator** button.
4. Under "Invite a collaborator to {your repository}", start typing the collaborator's username. Select the collaborator's username from the drop-down menu.
5. Click Add collaborator.

Note: **Only one /azp command per comment**.

Reference document：
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#comment-triggers